# How can I polymorphically interpret an Arrow-like GADT DSL?

Tags: haskell, dsl, dependent-type, gadt, free-monad

**TL;DR:** How do I write interpreters (`run :: Lang a b -> whatever`) for my `Lang` GADT?

---

I have a DSL:

```
data Lang a b where
  F :: Lang x y
  G :: Lang x y
```

I want to build programs like:

```
prog :: Lang a b
prog = G . F
```

And interpret them arbitrarily, where the replacement for `F` and `G` can be any function, so long as their types compose properly.

```
-- run ~= (+1) . fst
run :: Lang a b -> ((Int, b) -> Int)
run F = fst
run G = (+1) -- error: couldn't match type (Int, b) with Int
```

***Intepretation*** is my big issue. How do I write functions like:

```
run :: Lang a b -> whatever
-- eg reusing the variables
run :: Lang a b -> (a -> IO b)
```

I've added notions of composition to my language:

```
data Lang a b where
  ...

  Lift :: (a -> b) -> Lang a b
  Comp :: Lang b c -> Lang a b -> Lang a c

instance C.Category Lang where
  id = Lift id
  (.) = Comp
```

This allows me to build programs, but not interpret them. I understand the compiler's errors to me, when I try to instantiate one specific term to some type that is not the overall `run` fn's type.

This seems a bit like `Free` approaches, perhaps an Indexed Free? Relatedly, this is a much simplified version of my real problem, that largely uses Arrows, but, I think this simplified formulation encapsulates my issue.

Here's a runnable test environment:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module T15_GADT_Lang where

import qualified Control.Category as C

------------------------------
-- * My Lang

data Lang a b where
  -- | DSL
  F :: Lang x y
  G :: Lang x y

  -- | Composition
  Lift :: (a -> b) -> Lang a b
  Comp :: Lang b c -> Lang a b -> Lang a c

instance C.Category Lang where
  id = Lift id
  (.) = Comp

------------------------------
-- * Program A can be interpreted in 2 different ways

progA :: Lang a b
progA = F

runA1 :: Lang a b -> (Int -> String)
runA1 F x = show x <> "!"

runA2 :: Lang a b -> ([Double] -> String)
runA2 F x = show x <> "!"

progAWorksNicely = do
  putStrLn $ runA1 progA 123
  putStrLn $ runA2 progA [1..3]


------------------------------
-- * Program B, I can't interpret the interim functions indepenedently

progB :: Lang a b
progB = G C.. F

-- | get the fst and increment it
runB1 :: Lang a b -> ((Int, b) -> Int)
runB1 F = fst
runB1 G = (+1) -- error: couldn't match type (Int, b) with Int

-- | Get the head and duplicate it
runB2 :: Lang a b -> ([a] -> (a, a))
runB2 F xs = head xs -- you're giving an `a`, but it should be `(a,a)`
runB2 G x = (x, x)
```

Comment: `C..` looks awesome. Took me  20 minutes to decipher.

Comment: It looks like you expecting to `runB1 F` have different type then `runB1 G`. How it supposed to work?

Comment: The problem is that `G C.. F` is valid program and `F C.. G` is equally valid program. Until we aply it to some interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write these different interpretations using only `Lift` and `Comp`, but it is less obvious how to interpret `F` as both `fst` and `head` in a way that makes sense

```
-- > run (Lift (\x -> show x <> "!")) 1
-- "1!"
-- > run (Lift (\x -> show x <> "!")) [pi,pi]
-- "[3.141592653589793,3.141592653589793]!"
-- > run (Lift (1 +) `Comp` Lift fst) (100, "ok")
-- 101
-- dup a = (a, a)
-- >> run (Lift dup `Comp` Lift head) [1,2,3]
-- (1, 1)
run :: Lang a b -> (a -> b)
run (Comp f g) = run f . run g
run (Lift f)   = f
```

The problem with `F` and `G` is that their indices are completely universally quantified, that means that composing with them might as well be untyped because any input and any output is valid!

If you want type-safe composition of `G . F` their interpretation must connect to those types somehow so you must provide indexes for `Lang` that unify these two uses

```
run F = fst   :: (a, b) -> a
run G = (+) 1 ::           Int -> Int

run F = head :: [a] -> a
run G = dup  ::        a -> (a, a)
```

In the case of `Lift` the input and output types are clearly reflected in the indices. Each of them could be made into a separate constructors that are indexed differently.

```
Lift (\x -> show x <> "!") :: Lang Int      String
Lift (\x -> show x <> "!") :: Lang [Double] String
Lift fst                   :: Lang (a, b)   a
Lift (1 +)                 :: Lang Int      Int
Lift head                  :: Lang [a]      a
Lift dup                   :: Lang a        (a, a)
```

If you want to interpret `F` as `fst` and `G` as `(+ 1)` you you have the types match

```
type Lang :: Cat Type
data Lang a b where
  One   :: Lang (a, b) a
  Plus1 :: Lang Int    Int
  ..

-- > run (Plus1 . One) (100, 200)
-- 101
run :: Lang a b -> (a -> b)
run One   = fst
run Plus1 = (+) 1
..
```

you can similarly interpret as an IO-kleisli arrow

```
-- > runIO  (Plus1 . One) (100, 200)
-- One
-- (+) 1
-- 101
runIO :: Lang a b -> (a -> IO b)
runIO One ~(a, _) = do
  putStrLn "One"
  pure a
runIO Plus1 n = do
  putStrLn "(+) 1"
  pure (1 + n)
runIO (Comp f g) a = 
  (runIO f <=< runIO g) a
```

---

tangent

You can also interpret it by abstracting the constructors into methods of a type class and interpreting it constrained by that class

```
type Lang :: Cat Type
data Lang a b where
  One   :: Lang (a, b) a
  Plus1 :: Lang Int Int
  Lift  :: (a -> b) -> Lang a b
  Comp  :: Lang b c -> Lang a b -> Lang a c

type  Langc :: Cat Type -> Constraint
class Langc lang where
 one   :: lang (a, b) a
 plus1 :: lang Int    Int
 lift  :: (a -> b) -> lang a b
 comp  :: lang b c -> lang a b -> lang a c

run :: Lang a b -> (forall lang. Langc lang => lang a b)
run = \case
 One      -> one
 Plus1    -> plus1
 Lift f   -> lift f
 Comp f g -> comp (run f) (run g)
```

I imagine the aim is to treat `Lift id` as the identity of `Comp` like the category operations are. Language can be expressed as a "[free `Category`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/lulc3t/has_these_been_any_practical_application_of_ie/gp8gv8r/)"

```
type  Langc :: Cat Type -> Constraint
class Category cat => Langc cat where
 one   :: cat (a, b) a
 plus1 :: cat Int    Int
 lift  :: (a -> b) -> cat a b

run :: Lang a b -> (forall lang. Langc lang => lang a b)
run = \case
 One      -> one
 Plus1    -> plus1
 Lift f   -> lift f
 Comp f g -> run f . run g
```

or a free `Arrow` which has `arr :: Arrow arr => (a -> b) -> arr a b`

```
type  Langc :: Cat Type -> Constraint
class Arrow arr => Langc arr where
 one   :: cat (a, b) a
 plus1 :: cat Int    Int

run :: Lang a b -> (forall lang. Langc lang => lang a b)
run = \case
 One      -> one
 Plus1    -> plus1
 Lift f   -> arr f
 Comp f g -> run f . run g
```

Which can be interpreted at `Langc (->)` and `Langc (Kleisli IO)`.

In fact you can skip having an "initial" `Lang` encoding and define it as "final"

```
type Lang :: Cat Type
type Lang a b = (forall lang. Langc lang => lang a b)

f :: Lang (Int, a) Int
f = one >>> plus1

-- > run f (100, "ok")
-- 101
run :: Lang a b -> (a -> b)     -- requires: instance Langc (->)
run lang = lang
```

Comment: I don't see how it solves `runB1 F = fst` `runB1 G = (+1)` problem. Can you add example of how to use it similar to one in question?

Comment: I added it to the beginning

Comment: Don't worry if it doesn't make sense.. I didn't read the question carefully enough

Comment: Yep Looks like what Josh.F want to achieve is impossible because you have to have some constraints on your DSL primitives, otherwise compiler will be unable to typecheck. You will end up with `run` having type structurally similar to program you try to interpret. Otherwise compiler won't be able to typecheck your program. Or you could put all constraints in your DSL as you did. It is impossible to just write `G . F` because it depends on interpretation will it be valid program or not.

Comment: @Iceland_jack the free arrow/category sounds intriguing.  I still don't think this gives me complete polymorphism like I was hoping to get. Imagine a program `H . G . F`. I'm thinking of those DSL chunks as holes that need to be filled, and it'd be cool to fill them with any functions that mutually type check. Maybe I want `(h :: [y] -> b) . (g :: [x] -> [y]) . (f :: a -> [x])`, or maybe I want that inner list to actually be `(x, x)`. Ideally, `run` only pins down the entering `a` and `b`, nothing in between. Does that make sense?

Comment: You mentioned that `Lang` needs an index proving the types compose, I thought that's what `Comp` could do, but, clearly not quite...

Comment: Based on further reading, I'm wondering if this is related to [reflection](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection), or even `IxFree`. `IxFree` is commonly a free monad, I wonder if there's an indexed free arrow?